# MKMapView black screen

Tags: mkmapview, mapkit, instruments

anybody have uncaught crashes using the native MKMapKit?

We have an application with some maps to showing places or people around, if we access in and out the maps functionality repeatedly. And we move up and down over the map, to force the loading of the hidden parts of the cartography.

After some repetitions the screen turns black, and the application crash without any stacktrace message.

On the console appears before the message "Received memory warning" sometimes.

I profiled the application on simulator with zombies instrument, and with the device with allocations instrument, without any other result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we solved it moving the components with MKMapView to ARC, we'have a huge legacy code without ARC support.

With ARC enabled just for this components (using -fobjc-arc flag for compiler) works perfectly.

Regards